# Sunni viewpoint about "vasi" or "hojjat" in each era?

Tags: sunni, ahl-ul-bayt, imamah, hojjat

According to Shiism, in every era there must be one person to guide people and to help them obtain spiritual growth and fulfill their responsibilities towards their society. This person is not a prophet because Muhammad (peace be upon him) is the last prophet but instead he is a complete man who has knowledge of everything from Allah and is infallible (Ma‘sūm). These are the 12 Imams, from Ali Ibn Abi Talib to Hojjat Ibn al-Hassan, Mahdi.

This is because it is assumed that all men and women are fallible and their knowledge is very imperfect, therefore they must be guided by a Divinely appointed legitimate authority (called Imam, vasi, hojjat, etc.). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_%28Shia_doctrine%29).

My question is:

What is the Sunni view about this issue, i.e. having a person to guide people who is infallible and has knowledge of everything bestowed upon him by Allah?

If the belief is that there is no need to having such a man, what is the reason?

Comment: Infallibility of the creation isn't established as a factual thing.  This belief first needs to be proven as true before building upon it.

Comment: Vasi and Hojjat are two different concept. please do not mix them.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam-0-Alikum 
Dear

Quran says many Times.. ATEE-ULLAH-A WA ATEE-URRASOOL (Follow ALLAH and Follow Prophet Muhammad SAAW)

Quran Never said.. follow your aalims.

In Non Shiasm .. Muslims must follow only what Prophet Muhammad(SAAW) has told. if you are listening any Aalim or Imaam listen him carefully. But never apply all blindly upon yourself.

Prophet Muhammad SAAW said: It is enough for a liar who listens and tells others without verifying.

Now this becomes your duty to research for that. 
Prophet Muhammad SAAW also said on anther place: Seeking knowledge is obligatory upon every Muslim.

So this knowledge is not only of science, mathematics, computer studies etc. It basically includes ISLAMIC studies too.

Just look for ONE STAMPS at any statement. If that contains "Qaal-ALLAH-a" or "Qaal-aRasool ALLAH"(SAAW) (verify if you don't know) then follow it. otherwise these are the aalims who are making (diversions)

Otherwise same culture exists in Christians and Jewish. And they are known as "Fathers, Rahbars" etc.

You must be thinking who these Imams in Mosques are?. Then they are better teachers, they teach us, don't lead us.

### edited after commnets from abdolah

what is your opinion about this verse?: يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَطِيعُوا اللَّهَ وَأَطِيعُوا الرَّسُولَ وَأُولِي الْأَمْرِ مِنكُمْ –

This is the first part of  the verse form Sura-e-Nisaa . Ayat no. 59.
Complete ayat is...

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَطِيعُوا اللَّـهَ وَأَطِيعُوا
>   الرَّسُولَ وَأُولِي الْأَمْرِ مِنْكُمْ ۖ فَإِنْ تَنَازَعْتُمْ فِي
>   شَيْءٍ فَرُدُّوهُ إِلَى اللَّـهِ وَالرَّسُولِ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ
>   تُؤْمِنُونَ بِاللَّـهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ خَيْرٌ
>   وَأَحْسَنُ تَأْوِيلًا

And this is translated as...

> O you who believe! Obey Allah and obey the Messenger (Muhammad SAW),
>   and those of you (Muslims) who are in authority. (And) if you differ
>   in anything amongst yourselves, refer it to Allah and His Messenger
>   (SAW), if you believe in Allah and in the Last Day. That is better and
>   more suitable for final determination.

... This is very simple to understand. There are so many rules those are developed by our rulers (government) or country leaders. If we'll keep following them we'll stay safe other wise it may be harmful for us.

1. We are told to stop on "RED" signals .. This is not written in Ahadees/Quran to stop on RED signals..But this is the rule we've to follow.
2. In some countries vehicle are driven LHS and some do RHS. IF you are in LHS traffic country. You have to follow their rule of driving car in LHS regardless you are having whatever car.

If you Government passes some Orders you have to follow them...

> NOTE: Both these examples don't contradict with any verse of
>   QURAN or Hadees. That's why we are bound to follow them because ALLAH SWT 
>   ordered us in Quran.

But. if in some countries Having physical relations with opposite gender before marriage is LEIGLE... this doesn't mean you are allowed to do this because Quran said...

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَطِيعُوا اللَّـهَ وَأَطِيعُوا
>   الرَّسُولَ وَأُولِي الْأَمْرِ مِنْكُمْ ۖ

this is a contradiction with Islamic rules. And it is called "ZINA". Here you'll not follow your rulers (Government). but the 2nd part of this verse..
 فَإِنْ تَنَازَعْتُمْ فِي

> شَيْءٍ فَرُدُّوهُ إِلَى اللَّـهِ وَالرَّسُولِ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ
>   تُؤْمِنُونَ بِاللَّـهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ خَيْرٌ
>   وَأَحْسَنُ تَأْوِيلًا

Similarly Same gender marriage is allowed in America or some Non Muslim countries. Will you follow that???

I hope this will make you understand inshaALLAH.. (I'm sorry i'm not very good in english)

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism or for seeking clarification on a post; they are not for debating controversial points.