# Who was Allah's hojjat on Earth when Mohammad (saww) went to maraaj?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, shiism, miraj, hojjat

In Shia Islam there is this belief that there *has* to be one hojjat of Allah on Earth. He could be described as the

> [decisive argument of Allah over mankind](http://www.qul.org.au/library/duas-supplications/404-dua-tawassul-the-supplication-of-seeking-advocacy)

Further description found in the question [Sunni viewpoint about "vasi" or "hojjat" in each era?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12487)

The way it is described, it seems that this presences is ensured by Allah Himself.

There is also this belief that Mohammad(saww) went on a maraaj in which he went to the skies, beyond the point which Gabriel(as) couldn't go and had words with Allah.

Now, since Mohammad(saww) was than Allah's hojjat on Earth, so when he went to maraaj who was Allah hojjat on Earth?

I don't find the presence the Ali(as) on Earth as a sound explanation because he at that time was not the Imam, the hojjat (maybe that's incorrect) because Mohammad was still alive.

It's is said that when Mohammad(saww) got back from maraaj things were in the exact same position and condition the way they were when he left (the door chain still swings, the warmth on bed or door knob (not sure)). Which, scientifically speaking, could mean that he went and came back in zero time and therefore no time passed when there wasn't a hojjat present on Earth. Is that a possible and a valid explanation?

Comment: your question deserves an up vote but you can enhance it by dividing your questions one by one.

Comment: I don't get it. By dividing the question do you mean separate self-contained questions altogether? If so, then I actually thought about it and decided not to because the minor question are relevant, close coupled and things that could be a possible explanation. Splitting them up seemed redundant. If you still think it should be otherwise then bring it up as a [meta] discussion (or I could if you'd want me to) and let's see what the community proposes.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, regarding your significant query, hopefully the following link can be helpful for you to some extent and you can find what you need ... regarding Me'raj: http://www.al-islam.org/the-message-ayatullah-jafar-subhani/chapter-22-meraj-%E2%80%93-heavenly-ascension

Answer (score 1):

When Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) went to Moraaj, 3 other Imams were present on earth. They are Imam Ali a.s. and Imam Hasan a.s. and Imam Hussain a.s. so the earth has not been empty form infallible Imam.

There is a famous hadith among Shia that the Prophet (SAWW) said:

> وَاجْتَمَعَ اَهْلُ الْقِبْلَةِ عَلَی اَنَّ النَّبِیّ صلی الله علیه و
>   آله قالَ الْحَسَنُ وَالْحُسَیْنُ اِمامانِ قاما اَوْ قَعَدا
>
> Hasan and Hussain are Imams, uprising or sitting

Also Imam can be present in different places at the same time.

There is historical record about Imam Ali a.s. the some of Sahaba said last night Ali Ibn abi Talib were at our home for visiting and dinner. Other sahaba said the same thing until 40 person. So Imam Ali a.s. has been present in 40 different places at the same time. When one becomes one of Awlia of God such amazing abilities is granted to him by God. So the Prophet (SAWW) could present in both earth and skies at the same time.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/magazine/magart/2689/6603/77063?ParentID=25528)

Comment: Hassan and Hussien weren't even born when Miraj happened. And ali married Fatima after they went to Madinah. your answer is not correct...

Answer (score -1):

I think your assumption about hojjat issue is completely wrong. From Jesus(pbuh) to Mohammad(pbuh) there were 600 years and at least 6 prophets(or saint) should be in that time according to this assumption. But we don't know anything about them, anything about their writings or anything about their effects on people. We just know about the saints who corrupted Christianity. Also I don't think in Sunni belief, there is such rule. So, I think while Miraj, there was nobody in earth in such place, and there was no need also.

From a different perspective, Mohammad (pbuh) didn't go to the Andromeda Galaxy or something, obviously he levelled up to higher dimensions or something like that. The time is relative even in 3D universe. Zero time can be possible.

Comment: this question is of shias, plz note that...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted some people to think.