# Does Islam like every religion need to be reformed according to the times?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

If so how will this happen if Quran is the Word of God and therefore unchangeable??

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. These kinds of questions -especially with the poor content, details, focus delivered- lead to opinion-based answers and are hardly on topic. Here relevant posts [Is textual criticism important to Islamic studies?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/is-textual-criticism-important-to-islamic-studies) and [Sunni viewpoint about vasi or](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/sunni-viewpoint-about-vasi-or-hojjat-in-each-era)

Answer (score 1):

Nope it cannot be reformed because Islam was to be the final religion/message that God intended for mankind and is sufficient till the end of times.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the usage of the word 'supposedly' in your answer... Thank you.

Comment: Seeing that the word 'supposedly' was unnecessary and offered no value in my answer, I have removed it. Thanks.